# Dependency injection of type having nested dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I want to create a type which contains another dependency.

The reason is so that I can make the controller rely on a Infrastructure wrapper with more abstracted functions which then actually access the data layer.

So here is the wrapper having dependency of dbcontext

```
public Repository(IdbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

The controller constructor:

```
private readonly Repository _repo;

public TheController(IRepository repo)
{
    _repo = repo;
}
```

In the *Startup.cs*, `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDbContext<dbContext>(options =>         
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbContext")));
services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
```

In the *Program.cs*,

```
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
    var context = services.GetRequiredService<dbContext>();
    var _repo = services.GetRequiredService<IRepository>();
    ...
}
```

The `GetRequiredService<IRepository>()` fails with following Exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 
>         'namespace.Models.IdbContext' while attempting to activate 
>         'namespace.Repositories.Repository'.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associate the `IdbContext` interface with the `dbContext` implementation.

Assuming

```
public class dbContext: DbContext, IdbContext  {
    //...
}
```

It is failing because it was not registered and the provider does not know what to initialized when injecting `IdbContext` into the repository.

```
services.AddDbContext<IdbContext, dbContext>(options =>         
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("dbContext")));
services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository>();
```

Comment: You can also register it all at once like this: `services.AddDbContext<IdbContext, dbContext>(options => ...);`

Comment: @ShaunLuttin yes that is even simpler. Will update. Thank you.

Comment: When I tried this simpler form, I get error  "CS1061 C# 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for and no extension method accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @JP_medevice if you look at the source https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/d59be61006d78d507dea07a9779c3c4103821ca3/src/EFCore/EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.cs you will see that ShaunLuttin suggestion is accurate and should work

Answer (score 2):

You need to inject the same type that you register.

If you register a `dbContext`, then inject a `dbContext`.

```
services.AddDbContext<dbContext>(options => ...);

public Repository(dbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

If you register an `IdbContext`, then inject an `IdbContext`.

```
services.AddDbContext<IdbContext, dbContext>(options => ...);

public Repository(IdbContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Here is the latter option as a runnable demo:

https://github.com/shaunluttin/asp-net-core-db-context-interface-injection